# O que um objects.filter em Django retorna quando não encontra um objeto?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Basicamente é essa a minha pergunta, desculpa ser algo tão básico...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basicamente retorna vazio. Você pode por exemplo utilizar isso para validar se algo já existe ao fazer um filter, e verificar se o len é maior que zero, caso você use o objects.get para isso, retornará uma exception, então o filter é mais indicado nestes casos.

Por exemplo, se você quiser verificar se já existe um usuário com um certo e-mail:

user = User.objects.filter(email='email@teste.com')

Você pode verificar se existe um user com este e-mail simplesmente verificando e o len(user) é maior que zero, caso tente fazer isso com o .get, e a query não ache resultados, isso irá gerar uma exception do tipo DoesNotExist.

Você poderá encontrar mais informações sobre o ORM do Django na documentação que é bem detalhada: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/